# I don't want match abc with spaces AT ALL if followed by some other non space characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regex  https://regex101.com/r/7Cw1fy/1

```
abc(\s*)(?![\S]+)
```

The `abc` string matches, which is OK.

The `abc   cde` string matches, too, and this is not OK.

How can I match the first string only?

Comment: To avoid downvotes in the future, please consider providing all necessary details: 1) what the real input is like 2) what you need to get, 3) what you used, 4) In what way that does not work and what you expect. Showing your understanding of the regex you used is always an indicator you invested some effort into solving the problem yourself. Just saying "I have X, I used Y, but got T, but I expected Q. Why, can you help me" is not considered a well-researched regex problem and attracts downvoting even if it looks a completely valid SO question.

Comment: Does it mean you just need a regex that matches a word at the end of a string regardless of how many trailing whitespace there is? Or a word that is the whole string (with trailing spaces)? Again, that must be explained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use: `abc\s*$` ?

This will match only if there are no character other than a whitespace following 'abc'.

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/HdJ0FS/1

```
abc             -> matches
abc cde         -> no match
abc             -> match
abc      sdfds  -> no match
```

Comment: Both are good answers I don't know which one I should check :)

Comment: finally for my use case I rather need your regex :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
abc(?!\s*\S)(\s*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NjCWv8/1). *Details*:

- `abc` - a fixed string
- `(?!\s*\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces followed with a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location
- `(\s*)` - Group 1: zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: Both are good answers I don't know which one I should check :)

Comment: I choose this one because I always want groups.

Comment: @user310291 It depends on what your strings look like. If you have `abc` in a longer string, with text after `abc`, this solution is the best. If `abc` only appears at the end of string, you would need `abc\s*$` / `abc(\s*)$`. This should be explained in the question. Since it is not, I focused on fixing the immediate problem.